# $.ajax is giving no specified error and not running the php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using $.ajax into my php code. I can log the data sent and display it with `console.log` but when It reach the $.ajax . It is stopping whitout displaying a specified error or the url status . 
This how I'm calling my javascript function .

```
<div class="tagfav price" onclick="addfavourite(<?php echo $row_all_ad['skopeo_annonce_immo_id']; ?>,<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>)"></div>
```

this my javascript function .

```
function addfavourite(id_annonce,id_user){
    var  formData = "skopeo_user_id="+id_user+"&skopeo_annonce_immo_id="+id_annonce;
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/test.php",
        data: formData,     
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data, html) {
            console.log('added to favourite');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

the php file used into the url property of ajax is running into the navigator . It have only this line of code used to check the problem right now .

```
<?php die('test'); ?>
```

There is no a specified error displayed . although it is displaying URL POST problem, Firebug is not showing an url status problem too.
My function is stopping when it reach ajax .
It is not displaying the second `console.log` too .

**EDIT**

this is what I have displayed into firebug, as You see I'm getting my data without a problem
[image]

Comment: Do you see the console message from `console.log(formData)`?

Comment: don't use inline javascript. it's not 2003

Comment: @Barmar yes I'm displaying them without a problem . It begins when It reach $.ajax as I said .

Comment: @DavidFregoli please explain .

Comment: Is theere an error in the PHP log?

Comment: no it doesn't exist @Barmar

Comment: The console shows you're getting an error when you try to POST to the PHP script, that's why it's in red. Go into the Network tab to get more details.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using inline JS, you can actually store data you want to pass to your function in HTML5 `data-` attributes instead:

```
<div class="tagfav price" data-annonce-immo-id="<?php echo $row_all_ad['skopeo_annonce_immo_id']; ?>" data-user-id="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>"></div>
```

After that, listen to the click event on `.tagfav.price`. If the element is dynamically added you might want to consider listening to the click event bubbling to the `document` object instead. The values stored in HTML5 data attribute can be accessed via `.attr()` or `.data()`, but I personally prefer the former as the latter does not work well for dynamically changing `data-` attributes — this might not be the case in your application, but it's a good thing to note. `.data()` fetches the HTML5 data attribute on runtime and does not update the object if the DOM changes.

For the AJAX call, we can troubleshoot it by using deferred objects and promises, like `.fail()`, `.done()` and etc to see what is actually happening. The `.fail()` function that receives 3 arguments: `jqXHR`, `textStatus` and `errorThrown`. In the code below, your AJAX call will log an error message in the console if something went wrong.

```
$('.tagfav.price').click(function() {
    // Construct data object
    var formData = {
        'skopeo_user_id': $(this).attr('data-user-id'),
        'skopeo_annonce_immo_id': $(this).attr('data-annonce-immo-id')
    };

    // Make AJAX call
    var $fav = $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/test.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'JSON',  // Optional, jQuery intelligently guesses but good to have
        type: 'POST'
    });

    // Check AJAX status using deferred objects and promises
    $fav.done(function(data, html) {
        console.log('added to favourite');
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Also, some helpful pointers to check:

- Is your PHP script, `assets/test.php`, set to receive data by `$_POST`? You might want to check that.
- Is the same script echoing a JSON-encoded string that will be sent back to your script after the AJAX call is made? If so, use `dataType: 'JSON'` in your `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: I have tried your script . this what is displaying in the console.log 
 error:

Comment: Then it appears that your AJAX call is not going through, probably due to a server error. Did you check if your PHP script is working? Also, does the file `assets/test.php` exist?

Answer (score 1):

You should add single quotes around the parameters in the javascript function callback.

Othrewise, javascript will consider you arguments as javascript keywords like: `this`

So, change:

```
<div class="tagfav price" onclick="addfavourite(<?php echo $row_all_ad['skopeo_annonce_immo_id']; ?>,<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>)"></div>
```

To

```
<div class="tagfav price" onclick="addfavourite('<?php echo $row_all_ad['skopeo_annonce_immo_id']; ?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>')"></div>
```

Comment: If these IDs are numbers, they don't need to be strings.

Comment: I'm displaying my data without a problem into the console.log . they are not string but number so I have not that problem .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function addfavourite(id_annonce,id_user){
    var  formData = "skopeo_user_id="+id_user+"&skopeo_annonce_immo_id="+id_annonce;
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "./assets/test.php",
        data: {formData:formData},     
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

and in php

```
<?php echo($_POST['formData']); ?>
```

the output should be your formData